# bluez with simultaneous classic and low energy devices

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

Is it possible with bluez under Linux to connect to multiple classic and low energy devices at the same time? The bluez site isn't very helpful providing information like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I've managed to connect to 7 low energy devices at the same time.  The maximum varies depending on the hardware you're using.  You can also connect to multiple classic devices as well.

Here's some pseudo/snippet of C I used for connecting via L2CAP:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/l2cap.h>

char *bdaddr;
int cid = 0;
int psm = 0;
int bdaddr_type = BDADDR_LE_PUBLIC;
int err;
struct sockaddr_l2 addr;
int sock_fd = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_SEQPACKET, BTPROTO_L2CAP)

memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.l2_family = sock->sock_family;
str2ba(bdaddr, &addr.l2_bdaddr);

if (cid)
    addr.l2_cid = htobs(cid);
else
    addr.l2_psm = htobs(psm);

addr.l2_bdaddr_type = bdaddr_type;


err = connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
```

My code is a mix of C and Python so I tried to restructure it so it's just the C parts.  Everything was taken from reading the Bluez source code, specifically the `gatttool`.

**UPDATE:**
There's a bug in the linux kernel's bluez code in versions 3.4 and prior when dealing with L2CAP sockets.  Essentially, if you have more than one connection, it will mix them up so you get all your data on the last connection made.  So, the code I gave will only work on kernels 3.4 and prior if you only make one L2CAP connection.

Comment: This makes me optimistic! Could you provide any information about how you were able to connect to these devices? Did you use the bluez cli apps? Which version of bluez?

Comment: I used the same method as gatttool but in C code (looked at the gatttool source for reference).  I connected each device as a socket.  I used the 4.x code source as 5.x won't run on the kernel versions I need to use.

Comment: Is this any kind of source code that you could share? I've been looking for someone to consult about bluetooth/bluez support on a project. Any interest?

Comment: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/attrib/utils.c?id=4.101#n39  Unfortunately I'm already swamped with projects and can't take on anything new.

Comment: I'm marking this as answered as you have good reputation here, have pointed to some source code and you say that it works for you. Thank you for your response, information about this kind of thing is relatively sparse on the web. Any sources for web information about this stuff would be welcome.

Comment: I quickly modified some of my code for inclusion in the answer...  It's untested.

Comment: yeah, I found very little documentation too.  Everything was gleaned from looking at the source code for different command line tools for Bluez.